# Название плагина preview emmet?

Tags: веб-программирование, visual-studio-code, редактор

Подскажите название плагина preview emmet для vscode. Ну это такое окно, где будет показываться как будет выглядеть мой код, как на codepen.

с.м скриншот:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: ааа, он уже есть, не увидел :D